# Ubuntu doesn't start after software update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, freeze

After a software update Ubuntu asked me to restart it. Instead I shut it down, because I had to leave. On the next start attempt the start freezes without a real error (there is a standard message that pops up on every system start, but nothing new).

I can still (fully) boot in recovery mode. I tried the fix dpkg option and check disks, but that didn't change the result.

I had the same problem about a month ago after trying to install CUDA drivers manually - because the automatic installation failed. It was the exact same freeze, but because I see no error message, it could be something else of course. I fixed this error by reverting the manual changes (I don't remember what I did exactly). I have updated software before in that time period so I don't know whether it could actually be still from that.

I should mention that I run a dual boot where Ubuntu is the default starting os. I didn't boot windows inbetween (shutting linux down and restarting it).

I am unsure how to debug this problem further.

## Message

The message shown - but as far as I know it has always been shown - is:

```
[2.268282] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Cannot get irq -1 for the hotplug controller
[2.268289] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: pciehp: Notification initialization failed (-1)
/dev/nvme0n1p5: clean, 782387/67428352 files, 26148817/269699840 blocks
```

## Startup

1. Grub appears. I select Ubuntu
2. Initial message appears and system freezes
3. I shut it down by pressing the Off-Button (just once not a kill)

## Attempted Solutions

### Reinstalling Grub

Following these steps: https://www.maketecheasier.com/restore-grub-2-as-the-main-bootloader/ while being in recovery mode:

`sudo fdisk -l | grep "Linux"` only finds /dev/nvme0n1p5 ... Linux filesystem. After mounting that `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt` and checking that it actually contains files (as expected `bin dev home   lib64 media proc sbin swapfile usr boot etc lib libx32 mnt root snap sys var cdrom grub lib32 lost+found opt run srv tmp`) the installation `sudo grub-install --force --boot-directory=/mnt/ /dev/nvme0n1p5` fails with:

```
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

I checked and `fdisk -l` doesn't contain a `/dev/sda1` entry.

I also tried updating grub despite the failing of the installation which works without any issues.

The problem persists.

Comment: At GRUB, try booting an older kernel.

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but the system boots again. After an upgrade then it crashed again. Now I can upgrade without issue.